# How to send item form data in email using workflow in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I am new to SharePoint workflow and learning stage. I had one Access list form in SharePoint 2013. Our requirement is, when user fill data on list form and he\she click submit option, then an email need to send for IT group. In that email has "Title as subject line, Description as message body". I think we can achieve through workflow using SharePoint Designer, can anyone please share steps. Appreciated your help.

Comment: Yes, you can achieve this using designer workflow. But easy solution of all is use SharePoint default alerts to get the email and item data easily.

Comment: Creating alerts was not fulling my request, if possible please suggest workflow using SharePoint designer 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it using a SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow.

You can create a SharePoint group and use it to store the members of IT group. Or use an AD group to store the members of IT  group.

You can create a SharePoint 2010 platform workflow for the list with SharePoint Designer 2013, then set it like:
[image]

Note: In my image, I use "HR Group" as testing, you need to change it to "IT Group".

In addition, in the workflow Start options, you can set it like:
[image]